# Displaying the content of mysql table data in bootstrap table

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create table like this:

[Table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes)

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/pZ9hQ/)

And want to place data from mysql table whic has following structure:

```
Column  Type    Null    Default     Comments    MIME
sno     int(32)     No               
username    varchar(64)     No               
userid  varchar(32)     No               
tweet_text  varchar(256)    No               
text_id     varchar(32)     No               
time    varchar(32)     No               
month   varchar(32)     No               
year    varchar(32)     No               
date    varchar(32)     No               
user_follower_count     varchar(32)     No               
rt_count    varchar(32)     No               
constant    varchar(32)     No               
in_reply_to     varchar(128)    No
```

Issue:

1. Here table heading does not appear  properly. How to do?
2. How to add pagination. like 30 records on each page. then press next to get next 30 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap offers a list of classes to style your table.

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
```

is a bootstrap class.

In order to create a table like this,

include bootstrap file in your HTML header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Test</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">    


</head>
```

Then in body section, create your table using desired class.

```
<body>
<table class="table table-condensed">

<?php do {
... echo table rows and columns
while ($returned_rows = $mysql_num_rows); ?>


..</table>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks kk, I already did it here, http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/pZ9hQ/ but it does not show top header

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/pZ9hQ/
I have added the headings markup in your HTML in the fiddle. Have a look. It should solve the problem

Comment: Sorry you forgot to update the fiddle, it;s same as mine